# What does it mean by "wasn’t everybody saying"?

Tags: idioms, sentence, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

"As Mr Trump’s opponents called this a disaster, his supporters lambasted their criticism as hysterical—wasn’t everybody saying a year ago that it was sinister to have so many generals in the cabinet?"
What does it mean by "wasn’t everybody saying"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get to the meaning of a phrase using a contraction, break down the contraction first.

In this case, it would be 'was not'.

Therefore, 'was not everybody saying'

The writer is simply bringing up that many people were "saying a year ago that it was sinister to have so many generals in the cabinet?"

He is saying it in a provocative way in order to allow the other side to see his point.